# search api in loopback nodejs

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have a need to implement this api in loopback nodejs

```
https://myapi.com/part_numbers?part_number=1245,6787,89490,940044...
```

Any ideas on how to go about it ?
The path after part_number should accept atleast 100 partnumbers and then return me the result.

All the documentation that i have looked at in loopback talks abut only sending a get request to something like https://myapi.com/part_numbers?part_number=1245 
but not about sending for multiple comma separated values

Any ideas on how do i build this endpoint using loopback and nodejs I am using mysql as the backend datastore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am a maintainer of LoopBack and co-author of the pull request adding support for character-delimited arrays in input arguments.*

LoopBack provides a feature flag to enable comma-delimited array values in input arguments, this flag was added by https://github.com/strongloop/strong-remoting/pull/142. (Unfortunately it's not documented yet.)

How to use it:

1) Configure allowed delimiters in your `server/config.json`:

```
{
  "restApiRoot": "/api",
  // ...
  "rest": {
    "handleErrors": false,
    // ADD THE FOLLOWING LINE
    "arrayItemDelimiters": [","],
    // original content - keep it around:
    "normalizeHttpPath": false,
    "xml": false
  },
  // ...
}
```

2) Define a custom remote method (see [docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-methods.html)) accepting an argument of type "array of numbers". For example, assuming you have a model called `PartNumbers` already defined:

```
PartNumbers.get = function(numbers) {
  // replace this code with your implementation
  // here, we simply return back the parsed array
  return Promise.resolve(numbers);
};

PartNumbers.remoteMethod('get', {
  accepts: {
    arg: 'part_numbers',
    type: ['number'],
    required: true,
  },
  // modify "returns" to match your actual response format
  returns: {
    arg: 'data',
    type: 'object',
    root: true,
  },
  http: {verb: 'GET', path: '/'},
});
```

3) Start you application, open API Explorer at http://localhost:3000/explorer and give your new method a ride!